# ¿Como selecciono dos tablas no relacionadas a la vez en laravel?

Tags: laravel

Tengo actualmente un controlador que me trae toda una tabla.

```
public function panel(){
    $zonas = App\Zona::all();
    return view('panel', compact('zonas'));
}
```

Adicionalmente, quiero seleccionar desde la base de datos otra tabla, la tabla user creada con **make:auth**  para poder usarla en la misma vista.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simplemente pásalas igual que haces con zonas

```
$zonas = App\Zona::all();
$users = App\User::all();
return view('panel', compact('zonas','users'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usarlo de esta manera también, la ventaja de este es que puedes cambiarte el nombre a la variable tal como quieras utilizarla en la vista

> "nombre_a_utilizar_en_la_vista" => "variable"

```
$zonas = App\Zona::all();
$users = App\User::all();
return view('panel',["zonas"=>$zonas,"users"=>$users]);
```